# Python Dictionary Adding Values

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and I am using pandas to play around with data frames and data quality reports. At the moment I am able to read a .csv file into a data frame, display it and carry out a number of actions for different columns.

What I am trying to do is split up the column names into two different groups, preform different functions on the columns inside the groups and then print the results in a table.

My current approach is using a for loop with a nested if statement. I can get this to work for one function but my issue is storing the values. I have about 5 functions per column that I want to carry out and save with each column heading.

My question is, how do I create a dictionary entry with the column name and all the values of the functions following it?

```
for column_name, column in df.transpose().iterrows():
if column_name in CONT:
    #X = column_name
    count = (df[column_name].count())
    min = min(df[column_name])
    mean = (df[column_name].mean())
    #How to add results into dictionary entry for column_name
    d = (column_name:count,min,mean)

    print(d)
else:
    count2 = (df[column_name].count())
    mode = (df[column_name].mode())
    #How to add results into dictionary entry for column_name
    d = (column_name:count2, mode)
    print(d)
    i = 1
```

Comment: Can you add sample of your dataframe?

Comment: Why are you trying to get these statistics? Just to have a look at them, or are you planning to use them in another part of your program?

Comment: Just to practice python mostly, putting them together and then just displaying them in a table. @jezrael do you want some sample data or the dataframe call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that will compute the values and put them in a dict of dicts.

```
result_dict = {} # the dict in which you want to get the statistics

# the list of columns can be accessed through df.columns
for column_name in df.columns:
  col = df[column_name] # we get the column
  if column_name in CONT:
    stats = {} # we create a dict to keep the stats for this column
    stats['count'] = col.count()
    stats['mean'] = col.mean()
    stats['min'] = col.min()
    result_dict[column_name] = stats # we add the stats dict to our result_dict

  else:
    stats = {}
    stats['count'] = col.count()
    stats['mode'] = col.mode()
    result_dict[column_name]
```

At the end of this script, you'll have a dictionary containing one stats dictionary per column, and you can access the stats by doing, for example : `result_dict['my column']['mean']`

More generally, if you have a pandas DataFrame and you want to quickly get a few sample statistics, try using the `.describe()` method that will give you a nice array. By default, it only returns statistics for numeric columns, but call it that way to get information on all columns:

```
df.describe(include='all')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 1, 2, 3], 'c':[1, 9, 1, 7]})
print df
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  9
2  2  2  1
3  3  3  7

CONT = ['a', 'b']
count = df[CONT].count()
min = df[CONT].min()
mean = df[CONT].mean()

df1 = pd.concat([count, min, mean], axis=1, keys=['count','min','mean'])

print df1
   count  min  mean
a      4    1  1.75
b      4    1  1.75

print df1.to_dict(orient='index')
{'a': {'count': 4.0, 'mean': 1.75, 'min': 1.0}, 'b': {'count': 4.0, 'mean': 1.75, 'min': 1.0}}

print CONT
['a', 'b']

#remove items from columns which are not in CONT
CONT1 = [ x for x in df.columns.tolist() if x not in CONT ]
print CONT1
['c']

count = df[CONT1].count()
min = df[CONT1].min()
mean = df[CONT1].mean()

df2 = pd.concat([count, min, mean], axis=1, keys=['count','min','mean'])
print df2
   count  min  mean
c      4    1   4.5

print df2.to_dict(orient='index')
{'c': {'count': 4.0, 'mean': 4.5, 'min': 1.0}}
```